# What is wrong in sendto() arguments here?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

This is the server code portion of a UDP client-server program. Inside the while loop I called sendto() to write to the socket. But when I execute the program it says - 'Invalid Argument'. What is wrong with the sendto() arguments here ?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n,newsockfd;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t len;
   char mesg[1000];

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
   //printf("sockfd: %d\n",sockfd);

   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

   if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))<0)
   {
        printf("Problem in bind function\n");
   }

   len = sizeof(cliaddr);
   while(1)
     {
         memset(mesg,0,sizeof(mesg));
         gets(mesg);
         if (sendto(sockfd,mesg,100,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr) < 0))
         {
            error("Problem writing to socket");
         }

     }
}
```

PS: Changed the code from the previous one. Now getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got bracket position wrong.

This line:

```
if (sendto(sockfd,mesg,100,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr) < 0))
```

should be this instead:

```
if ( sendto(sockfd,mesg,100,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr)) < 0 )
```

What's more, since you have defined `len = sizeof(cliaddr)` outside your while loop and it doesn't get changed inside the loop, you can use it in your `sendto` command instead of `sizeof(cliaddr)`:

```
if ( sendto(sockfd,mesg,100,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, len) < 0 )
```

**Edit**:

After a more careful look, your `cliaddr` should be replaced with `servaddr`. The client should **send the message to the server**, and the fifth parameter in `sendto` command specifies the server address.

```
if (sendto(sockfd,mesg,strlen(mesg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
```

And the most important part you missed out is setting host address, i.e. server IP. Try the following code (it's based on your code, but with essential lines added/ modified):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

// change the host address to the appropriate one, this one is a loopback address
char host[10] = "127.0.0.1";

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n,newsockfd;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   struct hostent *sh;
   struct in_addr **addrs;
   socklen_t len;
   char mesg[1000];

   if ((sh=gethostbyname(host))==NULL) {             //get host's information
        printf("error when gethostbyname");
    }

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
   printf("sockfd: %d\n",sockfd);

   addrs = (struct in_addr **)sh->h_addr_list;

   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

   // setting address information
   memcpy(&(servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr), *addrs, sizeof(struct in_addr));
   bzero(&(servaddr.sin_zero), 8);

   if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))<0)
   {
        printf("Problem in bind function\n");
   }

   len = sizeof(servaddr);
   while(1)
     {
         memset(mesg,0,sizeof(mesg));
         gets(mesg);
         if (sendto(sockfd,mesg,strlen(mesg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len) < 0)
         {
            error("Problem writing to socket");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: @MdImranPavel: Maybe try `#include <sys/types.h>` ?

Comment: @MdImranPavel oh you didn't specify your `cliaddr`, it should be `servaddr` instead.

Comment: changed to this-- len = sizeof(servaddr);
and this -- if ( sendto(sockfd,mesg,100,0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len) < 0 )

Still not working. @nevets

Comment: @MdImranPavel oh I missed out some information I added to the code... You didn't specify your server IP. I am editing my post and you can try later :)

Comment: @MdImranPavel ok now try again :)

Comment: When a system call returns -1, don't just print an error message of your own devising. Print one that incorporates the result of `strerror(),` or call `perror(),` and do it immediately after the system call, not later on when you may have called other system calls and corrupted the value of `errno.`